# Not able to view constraints & Indexes of External data source objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have 2 DBs in Azure,

I have created tables in DB1 as

```
CREATE TABLE [Payment](
    [PaymentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PaymentDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Medicare] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Medicaid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VA] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pkPayment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PaymentID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I created External Data source for DB1 as FirstDb in DB2 to access the table Payment in DB2.

when I checked sp_help 'payment' for table Payment in DB1 i can see the Primary key & indexes avaialble

But when i check sp_help 'FirstDb.payment' for table from DB2 i cannot see the Primary keys & indexes.

why we cannot see the keys & indexes from DB2,

My doubt is if we query the payment table from DB2 using the External data source FirstDb will the indexes apply during execution.?

Comment: `FistDb` is the schema name?

Comment: @LONG its not schema name, i created External data source for DB1 in DB2, because in Azure SQL we cannot do cross database query to access tables.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple. In order to see object definitions between databases, you have to have the ability to query between databases. In Azure SQL Database, you don't have that ability. This is why you had to create an External Data source to even do the query between two databases.

Comment: yes in Azure SQL Database we dont have that ability, so we created External data source to access, which means that if we query the tables across DB using external datasource will it use the Indexes?

Comment: It will use the indexes, assuming queries are written correctly, etc., yes. You just can't reference them across databases.

Answer (score 2):

Query over external table is pushed down as T-SQL query to remote target (all parts of the original query that can be pushed-down, e.g. filters, aggregates). On the remote side (DB1 in your case) query optimization is happening again, so the query will potentially use any index that exist.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized queries are evaluated on the remote databases and will take advantage of the indexes on the remote database. On the query plan you will see on the remote query operator (remote query area) that filters applied on table columns on the WHERE clause are passed to the remote database.

Hope this helps.